# How to view single, trailing question mark in URL passed to Flask?

Tags: python, flask, url

I'm writing a Flask application to simulate a piece of equipment that is accessed via HTTP. Queries to the equipment end in a `?`; e.g. `http://10.10.10.10/:MN?` will return the model number.

I wrote the simulator to check the last character of the `request.url`. However, the question mark is not present in the request.

Test Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<command>")
def handle_route(command):
    resp = f"request.url: {request.url}"
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("127.0.0.1", 9023)
```

Checking `http://127.0.0.1:9023/:MN?` in a browser yields:

```
request.url: http://127.0.0.1:9023/:MN
```

Is the question mark in another Flask variable that I can access? I've checked `request.url`, `request.root_url`, `request.base_url`, `request.path`, and `request.query_string` and have not found the missing question mark.

Comment: The question mark is being stripped as it's irrelevant. Normally it would signify the start of query parameters but as there are none, it gets removed. The resource is :MN so why would you need to see a question mark? Unless the resource is :MN? in which case you could URL-encode it with %3F

Comment: I agree that it's irrelevant in regular use. The question mark is included in the equipment documentation, so I was trying to emulate that usage. Maybe the query works without the question mark, and is only there for readability. I don't have the equipment yet, so I can't check. Is it stripped by Flask or the browser?